# Parsing null character with boost spirit qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to parse a string with boost spirit qi, which has the following form:

```
"\0help@masonlive.gmu.edu\0test\r\n"
```

with the following grammar:
Here is the hpp:

```
class EmailGrammar :
    public boost::spirit::qi::grammar< const boost::uint8_t*,
        boost::tuple< boost::iterator_range< const boost::uint8_t*>,
                      boost::iterator_range< const boost::uint8_t*> >()>
{
public:
    const static EmailGrammar instance;

    EmailGrammar ();    

    /* omitting uninteresting stuff here i.e. constructors and assignment */

private:
    boost::spirit::qi::rule< const boost::uint8_t*,
        boost::tuple<
            boost::iterator_range< const boost::uint8_t*>,
            boost::iterator_range< const boost::uint8_t* >()> m_start;
};
```

and the cpp of the grammar looks like this:

```
EmailGrammar::EmailGrammar() :
    EmailGrammar::base_type(m_start),
    m_start()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    m_start = 
             (
             qi::lit('\0')
             >> (
                    qi::raw[*(qi::char_ - qi::lit('\0'))]
                )
             >> qi::lit('\0')
             >> (
                    qi::raw[*(qi::char_ - qi::eol)]
                )
             >> qi::eol >> qi::eoi
             );
}
```

Which I intend to use to parse the two strings and break them into two separate iterator ranges.

This is then called like so:

```
int main()
{
    typedef typename EmailGrammar::start_type::attr_type attr;

    std::string testStr("\0help@masonlive.gmu.edu\0test\r\n");

    // this is not done this way in the real code just as a test
    boost::iterator_range<const boost::uint8_t*> data =
        boost::make_iterator_range(
            reinterpret_cast< const boost::uint8_t* >(testStr.data()),
            reinterpret_cast< const boost::uint8_t* >(testStr.data() + testStr.length()));

    attr exposedAttribute;
    if (boost::spirit::qi::parse(data.begin(),
                                 data.end(),
                                 EmailGrammar::instance,
                                 exposedAttribute)
    {
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The problem appears to be in parsing the null terminator. I think this because when I add the `debug(m_rule);` to the code I get the xml output:

```
<unnamed-rule>
<try></try>
<fail/>
</unnamed-rule>
```

However. if I explicitly erase for example the first null terminator I get the output:

```
<unnamed-rule>
<try>help@masonlive.gmu.e</try>
<fail/>
</unnamed-rule>
```

Which leads to the questions:

- How does one parse null terminators with spirit I have look for documentation and haven't been able to find any information on it except a mention of null terminated strings at the very bottom of [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/basics.html) page which mentions the default models in spirit.
- Does spirit do look ahead in a manner that if the parser sees in the look ahead it doesn't end correctly it automatically fails?
- Is there any documentation I am missing that I can use to read up on this sort of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely the whole problem originates here:

```
std::string testStr("\0help@masonlive.gmu.edu\0test\r\n");
```

doesn't do what you think. It creates an empty string. Instead, specify the length of the raw literal/buffer:

```
std::string testStr("\0help@masonlive.gmu.edu\0test\r\n", 31);
```

#### BONUS

If you don't want to do the math/counting (you shouldn't!), make a helper:

```
template <typename Char, size_t N>
std::string bake(Char const (&p)[N], bool include_terminator = false) {
    return { p, p + N - (include_terminator?0:1) };
}
```

Which you can then use like:

```
std::string const testStr = bake("\0help@masonlive.gmu.edu\0test\r\n");
```

---

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24e418aa09a08d91)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using It = uint8_t const*;
using Range = boost::iterator_range<It>;
using Attribute = boost::tuple<Range, Range>;

class EmailGrammar : public qi::grammar<It, Attribute()> {
  public:
    const static EmailGrammar instance;

    EmailGrammar() : EmailGrammar::base_type(m_start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        m_start = 
            '\0' >> raw[*(char_ - '\0')] >> 
            '\0' >> raw[*(char_ - eol)] >> 
            eol >> eoi
            ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((m_start))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Attribute()> m_start;
};

const EmailGrammar EmailGrammar::instance {};

template <typename Char, size_t N>
std::string bake(Char const (&p)[N], bool include_terminator = false) {
    return { p, p + N - (include_terminator?0:1) };
}

int main() {
    std::string const testStr = bake("\0help@masonlive.gmu.edu\0test\r\n");

    It f = reinterpret_cast<It>(testStr.data()),
       l = f + testStr.length();

    Attribute exposedAttribute;
    if (boost::spirit::qi::parse(f, l, EmailGrammar::instance, exposedAttribute)) {
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
<m_start>
  <try></try>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[h, e, l, p, @, m, a, s, o, n, l, i, v, e, ., g, m, u, ., e, d, u], [t, e, s, t]]]</attributes>
</m_start>
success
```

Comment: Added a bonus feature: [let's bake a string](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11ecfd2d733df24a). Here's a take with your original attribute type (note the simplifications): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24e418aa09a08d91

Comment: The length of the string in my debugger in gdb 7.12 with gcc 4.8 was printing 31 strangely enough.

Comment: That's only true if you used different code. So, did you see anything else I did differently? (Since you accepted the answer). Oh by the way, later realized you can also use string literals: `"hello\0world"s` does the same as `bake("hello\0world")`

Comment: This still fails for my actual input. However, since your code clearly solves the problem I wrote up, I accepted the answer. You are correct, the actual code I am working in does something different. It uses a karma generator to do base 64 decoding to ascii and returns a string formatted like I originally posted. I wrote up this small example since the base 64 decoder was very large and I didn't want to post the entire thing. Also, I think we are using different versions of spirit or something since the length of my original string is reported as 31 by gdb despite starting with '\0'.

Comment: No version of `std::string` (that's the ISO standard C++ specification since c++03) has that behaviour with the given code, so no, different version don't explain that. Feel free to feel to post a new question if you're still stuck, but be sure to include a complete, self-contained example that *does* reproduce the issue.

Comment: Scratch that last part you are correct. It does have length zero I flubbed. The string I generate has length 31 though. Apologies for the confusion.